# Fatal Error when running Xcode 6.4 application

Tags: xcode, swift, runtime-error, fatal-error

Does anyone know the solution to this error that I get after running a Swift app in Xcode 6.4. The project builds successfully. The error only comes when running the project. Error:

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:
0x107d11000 <+0>: int3
```

->  0x107d11001 <+1>: nop (Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT)

Answer (score 0):

You have breakpoints enabled.
The blue arrow like thing is a breakpoint:
[image]

So you can do Command-7(keyboard short-cut) on a mac to disable breakpoints.
[image]

Comment: Then please post a screen shot of your full error message and code.